# Manage prefabs programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to find all prefabs defined/available in a Unity project programmatically?

This should include prefabs sitting in the Assets folder which are **not in the Resources folder**.

Use-cases range from dynamically resolving dependencies (from a name for example) to wanting to implement some central instantiation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path = Application.dataFolder;
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.prefab");
for(int i=0;i<files.Length;i++)
    Debug.Log(files[i];
```

[image]

If you wish to load the prefab into the scene:

```
var url = "file://....prefab";
var www = new WWW (url);
yield return www;
www.bytes[]; // This way, you have to convert it to game object yourself.
```

Comment: I assume there is no way to then load said prefab as a Object?

Comment: You can use WWW to load it programatically?